# Recompiling third party Java code in a restricted environment

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory

I have user-level access to Jenkins and cannot change the settings.xml for Maven due to access restrictions. When I want to mvn deploy, it expects to have a distributionManagement clause in the pom.xml. The code however comes from the internet and I rather don't change the pom.xml every time. Is there something I can do in Jenkins? I am considering using the Artifactory plugin because that is where I want to deploy.

Comment: A useful plugin is the config file provider. It provides a mechanism to manage config files for a build and special support for project specific Maven settings files. See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

Comment: Another options is have a settings file in your project workspace and run maven as follows "mvn -s localsettings.xml ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using mvn deploy from Jenkins, but specifying the repository to deploy to with the -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url system property.

Format: id::layout::url

id is the repository id to be used to get credentials from the settings.xml (i.e. central, snapshot)

layout should be "default", unless you are still using Maven1 (in which case it should be "legacy")

url is the URL for the repository you want to deploy to.

This is specified in the Maven documentation here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks! I've been using Maven and Jenkins for years, and Maven was meant to deploy to repositories like Artifactory, and Hudson/Jenkins was made to run Maven, so I'm a believer in simple clean implementations leveraging these tools. Furthermore, since Maven commands can be run exactly the same as on Jenkins elsewhere, it makes it easier to reproduce and debug problems occurring if one sticks to using Maven with Jenkins as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Artifactory plugin seems a good solution if you cannot use the Maven deploy goal.

With a simple mvn clean install command + the Artifactory plugin, you will be able to deploy where you want (if the Jenkins server has the relevant read/write access):

[image]